# Simple Javascript I don't know how to put the functions in the if-else statements

Tags: javascript, html, json, loops, if-statement

Hi please help me my code is almost complete but it only triggers the last button which is the square root option. It's supposed to look like a calculator which opens up a pop-up button with a text box where you can input your numbers. I cannot trigger the right operation.

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="calculate('addition')">
<input type="button" value="Subtract" onclick="calculate('subtraction')">
<input type="button" value="Multiply" onclick="calculate('multiplication')">
<input type="button" value="Divide" onclick="calculate('division')">
<input type="button" value="Modulo" onclick="calculate('modulo')">
<input type="button" value="Pow" onclick="calculate('pow')">
<input type="button" value="Factorial" onclick="calculate('factorial')">
<input type="button" value="Sqrt" onclick="calculate('sqrt')">


<script>
function calculate(addition)    {
    var x= prompt("What is your first number?", "");
    var y= prompt("What is your second number?", "");
    var z= parseInt(x)+parseInt(y);
    document.getElementById("z").value = z;
    }
function calculate(subtraction) {
    var x= prompt("What is your first number?", "");
    var y= prompt("What is your second number?", "");
    var z= parseInt(x)-parseInt(y);
    document.getElementById("z").value = z;
}

function calculate(multiplication)  {
    var x= prompt("What is your first number?", "");
    var y= prompt("What is your second number?", "");
    var z= parseInt(x)*parseInt(y)
    document.getElementById("z").value = z;
}

function calculate(division)    {
    var x= prompt("What is your first number?", "");
    var y= prompt("What is your second number?", "");
    var z= parseInt(x)/parseInt(y)
    document.getElementById("z").value = z;
}
function calculate(modulo)  {
    var x= prompt("What is your first number?", "");
    var y= prompt("What is your second number?", "");
    var z= parseInt(x)%parseInt(y)
    document.getElementById("z").value = z;
}

function calculate(pow) {
    var x= prompt("What is your first number?", "");
    var y= prompt("Raised to?", "");
    var i=1
    while (i<(parseInt(y)+1))   {
        var z= parseInt(x)*parseInt(x)
        i=parseInt(i)+1
        }
    document.getElementById("z").value = z;
}
function calculate(factorial)   {
    var x= prompt("What is your number?", "");
    var i=1
    var m=1
    while (m<(parseInt(x))) {
        i=parseInt(i)*((parseInt(m)+1))
        m=parseInt(m)+1
    }
    document.getElementById("z").value = i;
}
function calculate(sqrt)    {
    var x= prompt("What is your number?", "");
    i=1
    while (i%parseInt(x)!=0)    {
        z=(parseInt(x)%i)
        i=parseInt(i)+1
    }
    z=Math.sqrt(parseInt(x))
    document.getElementById("z").value = z;
}


</script>
```

Comment: uh, you're defining that function multiple times. a function name MUST be unique... you should have `function calculate(type) { if (type=='addition') { ... } else if (.....)`-type stuff, most likely. If you'd done ANY basic debugging, like checking your browser's error console, you'd have been told about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function overloading in JS based on parameter passed. You can write the calculate function once and handle different cases in it.

```
function calculate(op) {
  if (op == 'addition')//do addition
  else if (op == 'subtraction')//do subtraction
  ...
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH EVERYONE FOR HELPING ME! MY CODE WORKS NOW! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are redeclaring `calculate`. This is not necessary, but you need to evaluate the parameter. Based on the content, you do your calculation.

```
function calculate(operator) {
    var x, y, z;

    if (operator === 'addition') {
        x = parseInt(prompt("What is your first number?", ""), 10),
        y = parseInt(prompt("What is your second number?", ""), 10),
        z = x + y;
    } else if (operator === 'subtraction') {
        x = parseInt(prompt("What is your first number?", ""), 10),
        y = parseInt(prompt("What is your second number?", ""), 10),
        z = x - y;
    }
    document.getElementById("z").value = z;
}
```

For more than one comparison, you could use a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) operator.

```
switch (operator) {
    case 'addition':
        z = x + y;
        break; // to stop more testing
    case 'subtraction':
        z = x - y;
        break;
    // other cases
    default:
        z = 'unknown operator';
}
```

Comment: So in the //do something part, I should insert the actual operation (+ - * /) right? Sorry I'm new to this.